# Why does the object goes white, while the other same object doesn't? (Fixed)

Tags: lighting

I made two paper bags with paper strings. Then I added a background color. I don't know why some paper strings show the world background color while some strings are normal. How can I correct them to normal color? Thanks.
[image]

This is the shading nodes of the strings (They are all the same)
[image]

Light

[image]

World background shading
[image]

Comment: It's my first time asking a question in the blender forum. Please tell me what extra information I need to provide if it is not enough to explain the situation, thanks

Comment: Hello, are you sure that it has been assigned the good material? Maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: this is the blender file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=pR1ByE4X" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pR1ByE4X/)

I used shading nodes to make the material, so there was no image. But I added a logo image object and shrink wrap to the paper bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable their *Shadow Catcher* option:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works! You saved my assignment, thank you so much!